# CSS Indent text below image when it wraps

Tags: html, css

I've got the following modal, when it pops up there is an image to the left of the text. What I want is to have the text inline with the text above rather than wrap below the image.
Below is how it looks now
[image]

Heres how I want it to look

[image]

My HTML is like:

```css
.download-file-icon {
    height: 50px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.download-file-text {
    color: #828282;
}
.download-area-text {
    padding: 10px !important;
    font-size: 19px !important;
}

.download-area-div{
   
}
```

```html
<div class="download-area-div"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" class="download-file-icon"><a class="download-file-text" href="http://aFC-LN_20160830.pdf" target="_system" style="
    /* width:  100% !important; */
">File One with a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long filename that wraps</a> <br> <br><hr> <br></div><div class="download-area-div"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" class="download-file-icon"><a class="download-file-text" href="ac-model-1.xlsx" target="_system">All good </a> <br> <br> <br></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Soluton #1

Set `position:absolute` on the img and then leave some `padding-left` on the container

```css
.download-file-icon {
    height: 50px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.download-file-text {
    color: #828282;
}
.download-area-text {
    padding: 10px !important;
    font-size: 19px !important;
}

.download-area-div{
   padding-left: 70px;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="download-area-div"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" class="download-file-icon"><a class="download-file-text" href="http://aFC-LN_20160830.pdf" target="_system" style="
    /* width:  100% !important; */
">File One with a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long filename that wraps</a> <br> <br><hr> <br></div><div class="download-area-div"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" class="download-file-icon"><a class="download-file-text" href="ac-model-1.xlsx" target="_system">All good </a> <br> <br> <br></div>
```

### Solution #2

Use flexbox

```css
.download-file-icon {
    height: 50px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    flex: 0 0 50px;
}
.download-file-text {
    color: #828282;
}
.download-area-text {
    flex:1;
}

.download-area-div{
   display:flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="download-area-div"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" class="download-file-icon"><a class="download-file-text" href="http://aFC-LN_20160830.pdf" target="_system" style="
    /* width:  100% !important; */
">File One with a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long filename that wraps</a> <br> <br><hr> <br></div><div class="download-area-div"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" class="download-file-icon"><a class="download-file-text" href="ac-model-1.xlsx" target="_system">All good </a> <br> <br> <br></div>
```

### Solution #3

Create a new block formatting context by floating the image and adding `overflow:hidden` on the adjacent element (see [this post](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-block-formatting-contexts-in-css/#prevent-text-wrapping))

```css
.download-file-icon {
    height: 50px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.download-file-text {
    color: #828282;
}
.download-area-text {
    padding: 10px !important;
    font-size: 19px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.download-area-div{
   padding-left: 70px;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  float: left;
  }
```

```html
<div class="download-area-div"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" class="download-file-icon"><a class="download-file-text" href="http://aFC-LN_20160830.pdf" target="_system" style="
    /* width:  100% !important; */
">File One with a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long filename that wraps</a> <br> <br><hr> <br></div><div class="download-area-div"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" class="download-file-icon"><a class="download-file-text" href="ac-model-1.xlsx" target="_system">All good </a> <br> <br> <br></div>
```

Comment: Solution #3 doesn’t work, if you have longer text in the link. Floating the image on its own doesn’t do the trick (because having the text float _around_ the image is what float is supposed to do.) But making the link block and adding overflow:hidden makes it work with the floated image as well.

Comment: @CBroe yes you're right, I fixed the post. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You should float both inner columns to the left (making sure to clear the floats after the floated elements), and give each a percentage width. The width of the columns are up to you, it won't impact the width of the image itself. The width of the two columns, though, should both the be the same and they need to be floated to the left.

```css
.download-file-icon {
    height: 50px !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.download-file-text {
    color: #828282;
}
.download-area-text {
    padding: 10px !important;
    font-size: 19px !important;
}
.download-area-img {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
}

.download-area-desc {
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="download-area-div">
  <div class="download-area-img">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" class="download-file-icon">
  </div>
  <div class="download-area-desc">
    <a class="download-file-text" href="http://aFC-LN_20160830.pdf" target="_system">File One with a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long filename that wraps</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<hr><br>
<div class="download-area-div">
  <div class="download-area-img">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" class="download-file-icon">
  </div>
  <div class="download-area-desc">
    <a class="download-file-text" href="ac-model-1.xlsx" target="_system">All good </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```